# fputcsv posts empty data to csv file

Tags: php, html

I have a html form which collects, name, place, email on submission it posts to csv file.  But the php file creates a file without any data. Can any body help me in correcting the code. The full code is given below.
**HTML form CODE:**

```
<form method="post" name="excisedata" action="csv.php">
Enter Full Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
Enter Place /Location : <br>
<input type="text" name="place"><br>
Enter Valid Email :<br>
<input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET["name"];
$place = $_GET["place"];
$email = $_GET["email"];

$list = array($name, $place, $email,);

$file = fopen("mylist.csv","a");

foreach ($list as $line)  {
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));  }

fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Just change `fopen("mylist.csv","a")` to `fopen("mylist.csv","a+")` and try .

Comment: Tried, but not giving reluts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, i would add static values to your fputcsv function to make sure you have no file permissions problems.

```
 fputcsv($file,'bird,dog,fish');
```

once you confirm that is ok, try this:

your form is posting data, your processor is looking for GET data.

change

```
$name = $_GET["name"];
$place = $_GET["place"]; 
$email = $_GET["email"];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST["name"];  
$place = $_POST["place"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST["name"];
$place = $_POST["place"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$list = array($name, $place, $email,);

$file = fopen("mylist.csv","a+");
fputcsv($file,$list);  
fclose($file);
?>
```